# Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to play with Laravel today for the first time. I am getting the following error when I attempt to visit localhost/project/public:

> InvalidArgumentException
>   Route [login] not defined.

app/routes.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@redirect');
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@show');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@do');
Route::get('dashboard', 'DashboardController@show');
```

app/controllers/HomeController.php:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function redirect()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) 
            return Redirect::route('dashboard');

        return Redirect::route('login');
    }

}
```

app/controllers/LoginContoller.php:

```
<?php

class LoginController extends Controller {

    public function show()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) 
            return Redirect::route('dashboard');

        return View::make('login');
    }

    public function do()
    {
        // do login
    }

}
```

app/controllers/DashboardController.php:

```
<?php

class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function show()
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) 
            return Redirect::route('login');

        return View::make('dashboard');
    }

}
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You're trying to redirect to a [named route](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes) whose name is `login`, but you have no routes with that name:

```
Route::post('login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@do']);
```

The `'as'` portion of the second parameter defines the name of the route. The first string parameter defines its *route*.

Comment: Wouldn't `Route::post('login', 'LoginController@do')->name('login');` work the same and read a little cleaner?

Comment: @Anovative Perhaps, that's a judgement call though, but you're right it should work just the same. I'm not sure off the top of my head if that functionality existed in L4, and I think this question was asked before L5 came out (though I'm also unsure of that ATM, too).

Comment: Thanks  we can do in this way `Route::post('login', 'LoginController@do')->name('login');` or  `Route::post('login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@do']);`

Comment: With laravel 8 following route works great. Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('/auth/login');
})->name('login');

Answer (score 146):

Try to add this at Header of your request: `Accept=application/json` [postman or insomnia add header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJUgX.png)

Comment: the message i got is `Unauthenticated`. why was that?

Comment: this is not the answer. sometimes you want to test routes without providing any header at all, specially not `Accept`

Comment: This answer explains why it behaves like that. But is there a simple way to get this response for all the routes passing through the `api` middleware instead of relying on the request header? @jihon chacolla

Comment: This is *NOT* an answer. This is how to skirt around the problem. Even if you should be providing the headers under normal use the application should handle this use case with something better than 500 response codes.

Answer (score 60):

In app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('auth.login'));
}
```

Comment: yeah, but it is a pity that Laravel hadcoded this route(( it's not obvious for newbies

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Don't forget to add this to the top of the file: `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;`

Comment: This is took me 1 week to find, gawd damn someone should pull request to update this, as this is not flexible when you have custom guards or custom login route names.

Comment: _This_ is the real answer to _why_ are they getting the error, it's a shame this is still a thing in 2023... Totally opaque to a new user.
I'm a seasoned programmer (in PHP and beyond) working as a Platform Engineer Consultant and worked on many Lumen & several pre-setup Laravel projects and this is my first time trying it out from scratch as Lumen is dead, and so far it's things like this that make it so hard to use.

All I'm trying to do is get an API set up and things like this are just so infuriating, and hitting the default supplied API controller in the browser gives you that error.

Answer (score 16):

You need to add the following line to your web.php routes file:

```
Auth::routes();
```

In case you have custom auth routes, make sure you /login route has 'as' => 'login'

Answer (score 15):

Laravel has introduced [Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes) in Laravel 4.2.

> **WHAT IS NAMED ROUTES?**
>
> *Named Routes allows you to give names to your router path. Hence using the name we can call the routes in required file.*

---

> **HOW TO CREATE NAMED ROUTES?**
>
> Named Routes created in two different way : **as** and **name()**

**METHOD 1:**

```
Route::get('about',array('as'=>'about-as',function()
    {
            return view('about');
     }
));
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
 Route::get('about',function()
{
 return view('about');
})->name('about-as');
```

**How we use in views?**

```
<a href="{{ URL::route("about-as") }}">about-as</a>
```

Hence laravel *'middleware'=>'auth'* has already predefined for redirect as login page if user has not yet logged in.Hence we should use **as** keyword

```
    Route::get('login',array('as'=>'login',function(){
    return view('login');
}));
```

Answer (score 10):

In case of API , or let say while implementing JWT . JWT middleware throws this exception when it couldn't find the token and will try to redirect to the log in route.
Since it couldn't find any log in route specified it throws this exception .
You can change the route in "app\Exceptions\Handler.php"

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception){
        return $request->expectsJson()
             ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
            : redirect()->guest(route('ROUTENAME'));
}
```

Comment: For others who find this solution relevant... ensure you're sending the `Accept: application/json` header. That will ensure you get a JSON + HTTP 401 response (as expected). If you don't send that header Laravel will attempt to send you to the `/login` route (and you'll get the same issue as the OP).

Comment: In Laravel 5.7 route checking happens before exception throwing, so the above won't work. There needs to be a defined route with `login` name.

Answer (score 6):

Am late to the party. if your expectation is some sort of json returned other than being redirected, then edit the exception handler so do just that.

Go to go to `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`
Then edit this code:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

to

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'errors' => [
                    'status' => 401,
                    'message' => 'Unauthenticated',
                ]
            ], 401
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this error recently after using Laravel's built-in authentication routing using `php artisan make:auth`. When you run that command, these new routes are added to your web.php file:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I must have accidentally deleted these routes.  Running `php artisan make:auth` again restored the routes and solved the problem.  I'm running Laravel 5.5.28.

Answer (score 5):

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
return view('login');})->name('login');
```

Name your login route if using your own custom auth system.

Answer (score 4):

Try this method:

look for this file

> "RedirectifAuthenticated.php"

update the following as you would prefer

```
 if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
   return redirect('/');
 }
```

$guard as an arg will take in the name of the custom guard you have set eg. "admin" then it should be like this.

```
if (Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
  return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
}else{
  return redirect('/admin/login');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login')
```

works very well and it is clean and self-explanatory

Answer (score 3):

## Laravel ^5.7

#### The [Authenticate](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/42c2a7ee2774cc0e5e2ff0243872606ef84ee9a5/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L18) Middleware

Laravel ^5.7 includes new middleware to handle and redirect unauthenticated users.

It works well with "web" guard... of course the "**login**" route (or whatever you name your login route) should be defined in web.php.

the problem is when your are  using custom guard. Different guard would redirect unauthenticated users to different route.

here's a quick workaround based on [John](https://github.com/ankurk91)'s response (it works for me).

---

app/Http/Middleware/**Authenticate**.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guards = [];




    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string[]  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $this->guards = $guards;

        return parent::handle($request, $next, ...$guards);
    }




    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {

            if (in_array('admin', $this->guards)) {

                return route('admin.login');
            }

            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

---

Source : Issue [#26292](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26292)

Answer (score 3):

If using `passport` as `api` do:

*routes/web.php:*

```
Route::get('login', function() {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized.'], 401);
});

Route::post('login', [ 'as' => 'login']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace in your views (blade files) all:

`{{route('/')}}`  ----- by ----> `{{url('/')}}`

Answer (score 2):

If someone getting this from a rest client (ex. Postman) - You need to set the Header to Accept application/json.

To do this on postman, click on the Headers tab, and add a new key 'Accept' and type the value 'application/json'.

Answer (score 2):

**Adding this for the future me.**
I encountered this because I was reusing Laravel's "HomeController", and adding my custom functions to it. Note that this controller calls the `auth` middleware in its `__construct()` method as shown below, which means that all functions must be authenticated. No wonder it tries to take you to login page first. So, if you are not using Laravel's authentication scafffolding, you will be in a mess. Disable the constructor, or do as you seem fit, now that you know what is happening.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//In Laravel 8
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'do'])->name('login');
```

Answer (score 2):

**Route must be valid, should give route name.**

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'v1'
], function () {
    Route::post('/login', [userController::class, 'loginAction'])->name('login');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Laravel 8 I face the problem while access home URL after creating login register system**

First there is no route exists with the name login.

Just add a route name like this:

**for single method like**

```
Route::post('put url here',[Your Controller::class,'method name'])->name('login');
```

**for multiple method like**

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'put url here',[Your Controller::class,'method name'])->name('login');
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah the trick was to add a name to the route `->name("login");`

Answer (score 1):

In **Laravel 10** project, there's a HARDCODED route name called `login` in **app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php** file ([link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php#L15)):

```
protected function redirectTo(Request $request): ?string
{
   return $request->expectsJson() ? null : route('login'); // <--- !
}
```

When you make a route for your login page **with a different name** - like `signin` - It causes such an error to occur!

So you must rename Laravel's default route name(`login`) to your own(`xyz`), or rename yours(`xyz`) to Laravel's one(`login`).

Answer (score 0):

I run this command in terminal

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Then it's solved