# Auth::id() can't find user id and return null, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am setting like and unlike options on articles. but in LikeController there is problem. when I push the like button it says ->

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into `likes` (`user_id`, `article_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 5, 2019-05-30 07:58:34,
>   2019-05-30 07:58:34))

### Updated JWT and Routes

Like model:

```
class Like extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    public $with = ["user"];

    protected $fillable = ["user_id", "article_id"];

    public function article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Article");
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User");
    }
}
```

and LikeController:

```
use Auth;
use App\Article;
use App\Like;

public function like($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);

    $like =  Like::create([
        "user_id" => Auth::id(),
        "article_id" => $article->id
    ]);

    return Like::find($like->id);
}

public function unlike($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);

    Like::where("user_id", Auth::id())
        ->where("article_id", $article->id)
        ->first()
        ->delete();

    return 1;
}
```

I am not very sure why `Auth::id()` can't find the user id and return null?

Using JWT with vue.js

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {

  Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
  Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
  Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
  Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
  Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});

Route::get("/like/{id}", [
        "uses" => "LikeController@like"
    ]);
Route::get("/unlike/{id}", [
        "uses" => "LikeController@unlike"
    ]);
```

**AuthController** and **User**

to set controller and user model I followed the docs: https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/

Comment: check Auth::user()->id;

Comment: did you login successfully in the app?

Comment: yes, I did... but I am using JWT with vue.js is it the reason? maybe?

Comment: `using JWT with vue.js` that you can't use Auth::user(). You must use `$user   = JWTAuth::toUser($params['token'])`

Comment: Please provide more information on how JWT is implemented, i.e. are you using some package (what it is), how is the JWT auth forced to your controllers/routes, providing the routes config might be useful too.

Comment: I updated the question: with route etc. could you please check it out. @CvetanMihaylov

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have not protected your LikeController routes with auth.

Unless you have something like this in your `LikeController` for constructor:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }
```

then you should have your LikeController routes protected like this:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
], function ($router) {

    Route::get("/like/{id}", [
        "uses" => "LikeController@like"
    ]);
    Route::get("/unlike/{id}", [
        "uses" => "LikeController@unlike"
    ]);

});
```

Then the correct way of getting the logged in used is

```
auth('api')->user()
```

or

```
Auth::guard('api')->user()
```

Comment: okay, I tried it. now error is changed. `Route [login] not defined.` and  `throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");`

Comment: Please refer to this discussion about named routes:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303783/route-login-not-defined/29303878
(you might need to define the login route like this:
`Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login']); `
)

Also it might be useful if you provide your `AuthConroller` in the question too.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing Auth as such

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

and getting the ID like this:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$id = $user->id;
```

Hope this helps

Add this middelware on kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ],
];
```

this link might help :
[Answer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133361/laravel-5-4-get-logged-in-user-id-inside-construct)

Comment: okay, the error is changed now. it's says `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Updated Answer.

Comment: I tried update, but result is same. `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth::user()->id
```

use this code

Answer (score 0):

**first:** ensure that   `route` or `Controller` protected by auth middleware.

**second:** ensure that you are using correct `guard` for auth, if using `multiple guard`.

```
you should specify your guard name like this: `Auth::guard('admin')->id()`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to specify the `middleware => api` from the route groups. Also include the `like` related routes Or any protected routes within this routegroup.

`config/auth.php` shoud be updated as

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

...

'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

**In `routes/api.php`**

```
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->name('login');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function ($router) {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
        Route::post('register', 'AuthController@register');
        # Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login'); // commented.
        Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
        Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

    });

    Route::get("/like/{id}", [
        "uses" => "LikeController@like"
    ]);
    Route::get("/unlike/{id}", [
        "uses" => "LikeController@unlike"
    ]);

});
```

Comment: thank you, i did exactly the same but  still same error. `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: by the way if I insert other routes inside the group then there is an error popping up that says : TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: You can exclude \login out of the group. or can add. `public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }`

Comment: okay, you lost me there :) if you edit your answer I will appreciate

Comment: @parabellum try the solution now.

Comment: okay, it s telling me `Route [login] not defined`. and `throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");`

Comment: @parabellum try now. `\login` route should be named as `->name('login')`

Comment: @parabellum does this help?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it doesn't help... it's really trouble some...

Comment: @parabellum does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok ,

so i was also having that issue with my app when i was using jwt with vue js.
for getting current `Auth::user()`.

You need to pass token with your request.
if you check jwt core file, It getting user from token.
and you are not passing token I guess.

If yes then please pass token along with your request.
And also check the documentation of `jwt`. did you install your package properly?
remember for laravel 5.5 or greater, that package version to use is `jwt > 1.0.0`
also, check the documentation of that version properly.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use passport from Laravel where you have OAuth2 :-)

Laravel Documentation about Laravel Passport say:

> Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport,
>   which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel
>   application in a matter of minutes. Passport is built on top of the
>   League OAuth2 server that is maintained by Andy Millington and Simon
>   Hamp.

[You can look more information here where you see Laravel Passport Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport)

Answer (score 0):

Check if User is authenticated or not,
and don't forgot to use Auth class.

```
use Auth;
```

check if auth than delete,
And Use Auth::user()->id

```
if (Auth::user())
{
   Like::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)
    ->where("article_id", $article->id)
    ->first()
    ->delete();
}
```