# Laravel 7.6 - Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to build a simple rest api using the latest version of Laravel for a quite simple e-learning platform that I'm building using Reactjs. So far, everything seemed to be going well but then this error appeared. The strange thing is that, this error occurs only in two routes instead all the others work perfectly. This is a capure of my api.php file:

[image]

The routes that do not work are "posts" and "courses", as I have already said, the others work well, the only thing is that, as regards "teachers", "lessons" and "specialties", I cannot understand why, for example, if I make a petition with the POST method to "/ specialties / id", the requested data is not found.
Could any of you help me to solve these problems?

This, instead, is a capture of my "specialties" table file:

[image]

and finally, these are the capture of my "SpecialtyController" file:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303783/route-login-not-defined

Comment: Are you trying to access the login route ? or you're trying to post something using login route?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response guys. Yes I tried to post something using login route and I can do it without any problem for all the routes but the routes I have indicated. I cannot understand what I'm doing bad.

Comment: `Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login')->name('login');` try this?

Comment: Your question title says login not defined, while further, you are saying "posts" and "courses" not working and others working.
It seems your question is not clear.

Comment: I immediately try your suggestion emotality

Comment: @emotality i tried your suggestion but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how your routes are mapped, it can be `login`, `api.login`, `web.login` etc. Check the name of your login route with `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @emotality these are the captures of my routes, I have just done "php artisan route:list"

[link](https://i.ibb.co/k9tTyJH/01.png)
[link](https://i.ibb.co/mNJGsJ5/02.png)
[link](https://i.ibb.co/RHYmyxz/03.png)

Comment: I don't think you understand..this is gonna be too much chat here.. check my profile and get in contact if you want to..