# laravel 8 auth Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication, laravel-8

'Route [login] not defined ..'
I'm new to Laravel. I want to make a login system myself, but I still have not solved this error. I am logging in but the user appears blank on the other page, I still cannot control it. I want to use the user restrictions on other pages, how can I do this.

web.php

```
Route::post('login', [userLogin::class, 'loginPost'])->name('login.post');

Route::get('student/home', [studentHome::class, 'index'] )->name('student.home')->middleware('auth:students');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
```

userLoginController.php

```
public function loginPost(Request $request)
{          
 if(auth::guard('students')->attempt(['email'=>$request->student_mail,'password'=>$request->student_password],false))
    {
       //dd(Auth::guard('students')->check());
               
       return redirect()->intended('student.home');
             
     }
     else 
     {
       echo "yannlış";
       
      }
}
```

auth.php

```
 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'students',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'students' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\students::class,
        ],
```

Comment: how actually you have printed the route in you blade file. ?

Comment: you don't have any route named 'login', you have to name a route 'login'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303783/route-login-not-defined , Please refer here

Comment: The topics you mentioned did not help much. I have examined before. Can you give me more clear examples on this issue.

Comment: you don't have any route named `login`. you have to have a route named `login` since that is where the `auth` middleware will redirect unauthenticated users to, unless you want to go into that middleware and change where the redirect is going to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the login route which is used to display the login form. Try naming your root:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('login');
})->name('login');
```

Or you can add a separate route depending on what you are looking for.

```php
Route::get('login', [UserLogin::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
```

Comment: Ok, but what about a rest api context ? Using nuxt as a client, for example. Then Laravel is not supposed to serve the view. I think in that context, the change has to be done in the middleware/Athenticate.php within the RedirectTo function, no ?

Answer (score 1):

I run into this error when i was learning creating an API using laravel passport middleware, it redirects by default to the `GET` login route, so i had to add like the previous comment said in my `web.php`.

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login');
})->name('login');
```