# Route type delete does not work in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have following route and works

```
Route::post("delete-role", [RoleApiController::class, "Remove"]);
```

I tested it through postman like this

```
http://localhost/delete-role?api_token=hcvhjbhjb12khjbjhc876
```

Now, if I change above route and convert to type delete..

```
Route::delete("delete-role/{role_id}", [RoleApiController::class, "Remove"]);
```

it does not work. I get below error. It seems to be the reason that the api_token is missing.

[image]

I get same error when trying to update route like below

```
Route::delete("delete-role/{role_id}/{api_token}", [RoleApiController::class, "Remove"]);
```

Comment: "_Route [login] not defined_" seems to be the cause

Comment: that comes because api_token is not defined. This error never comes if I supply api_token and type is post.

Comment: Define this route or change it in Authenticate middleware

Comment: @Pankaj is the `login` route defined?

Comment: I am using laravel for api purpose. Allow me to explain the reason for this issue. when I declare route of type post, it works but when I set it to delete, it works partially because api_token is not found and auth validation fires.

Comment: as per the route `/{api_token}` you should pass the token. or try removing `/{api_token}`

Comment: I tried passing /{role_id}/{api_token}  but did not work, it just does not detect the token

Comment: if your route is enclosed within `auth` middleware then it will ask for authentications.  can you please share a screenshot of your route file?

Comment: did you try to add to header: 
`Accept: application/json` and `Content-type: application/json`

Comment: Have you encountered any other error beside Route {login} not defined? Also upon this error is the role deleted for database? I mean the error seems the controller is invoked and login route is missing. OR before controller code is invoked, somewhere in auth middleware you are being redirected to login route. Lastly, Please run php artisan route:list and verify the login route is present.

Comment: @Pankaj how do you know which role to be deleted in here `Route::post("delete-role", [RoleApiController::class, "Remove"]);`

Comment: what is this `api_token=hcvhjbhjb12khjbjhc876`? laravel  `csrf()` token?

Comment: We need to what do you have in web.php & api.php file. Probably, this thread could help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303783/route-login-not-defined

Answer (score 2):

You have to set header of your request as:

```
"Accept": "application/json"
```

in postman.

If you don't set the required `header` for api, `Laravel Passport` can't understand request as an API client and so it will redirect to a /login page for the web.

Or you can set a middleware to check it in code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!in_array($request->headers->get('accept'), ['application/json', 'Application/Json']))
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an incomplete details. but I see few issues here.

1. You seem to be using web routes for your API requests which is a bad set-up
2. You do not have a route with `login` name.

based on the error you posted, your request seems to successfully destroyed the token and logged you out, then called the middleware `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` which supposed to redirect your request to login route which does not exist and the reason you are getting that error.

You can see from that `Authenticate` middleware it will supposed to redirect you to login route for unauthenticated request. thats why you need to use the api routes so you can handle the response manually

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not so sure about this, but the reason you are not getting the same issue with your POST request is probably because your POST request does not call the Authenticate `middleware` or whatever in your routes file or class function that calls the authenticate middleware.

But again, just use api routes if you don't want un-authenticated request to automatically redirect your request to login routes which does not exist in your application

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that he doesn't define route ('login'),
add in Exceptions/Handler.php

```
 $this->renderable(function (AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return response()->json(['meassge' => 'Unauthenticated']);
          
        }
    });
```

Then you should use Passport Or Sanctum for auth with Api,
Continue from here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport

Answer (score -1):

Probably, this thread could help you. [Route [login] not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303783/route-login-not-defined)

(OR)

You need to setup auth scaffolding to get `login` route defined.

***Important: your project will be overridden if you setup auth scaffold.***

So, I would only recommend doing this if it is a new project or a testing app.

See this for [detail doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication) but install [Laravel Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze) would be suffice.

Answer (score -1):

It Appears you have called route('login') without having defined it in your routes, Please remove route('login') from your code or define it in your routes. eg::

```
Route::get('login', [YourController::class, 'methodName'])->name('login');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).